# Atomic и изменение порядка операций компилятором

Tags: c, многопоточность

Обязан ли компилятор сохранять порядок выполнения инструкций, если в многопоточной программе вот так использовать атомарную переменную:

```
volatile atomic_char flag = 0;
int fd;
```

в первом потоке :

```
...   
atomic_store(&flag, 1);  
close(fd);
...
```

во втором потоке:

```
...  
if(select(fd+1, ...) == -1){  
  if(atomic_load(&flag) == 1){  
    exit(0);  
  }
  else  
    printf("Select() error!");   
}   
...
```

?
Когда-то уже задавала схожий вопрос о *volatile*, и меня убедили, что от перестановок он не спасает. Не хотелось бы добавлять мьютекс для одного флажка, если только это не единственно верный вариант.

Используемая система - FreeBSD, компилятор - GCC

Comment: Какой порядок вы хотите чтобы сохранился? Разные потоки если не синхронизировать, то их выполнение независимо друг от друга.

Comment: Хочу, чтобы не получилось, что вызов select() завершился с ошибкой после закрытия дескриптора, а flag все еще установлен в 0.

Comment: @margosh, а что на самом деле Вас тут волнует? Закрыл ли при прерывании select-а сигналом (не отслеживаете же Вы свои ошибки в коде  (кроме ENOMEM) таким образом) дескриптор `fd` первый поток или кто-то другой?

Comment: Я что хочу сказать. Если задача в том, что получив прерывание надо выйти если `fd` закрыт, то это же можно просто проверить, вызвав, например, `fcntl()`.

Comment: @avp, добавлю что это если код под linux, использование из под windows `fcntl()` недоступно.

Comment: @avp, в обработке ошибки от select() в реальном коде - вывод сообщения об ошибке. Но оно не должно выводиться, если произошло штатное завершение процесса. В первом потоке - как раз штатное завершение, но второй может в это время висеть на дескрипторе, и если flag не будет выставлен - выведет сообщение об ошибке... Поправлю наверное, чтобы понятнее было.

Comment: Ну, да, извините, это я что-то ошибся. В самом деле, при уже закрытом `fd` select вернет -1 и установит errno в EBADF. Но никакой мьютекс  в этом случае Вам тоже не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

В пределах одного потока команды выполняются строго последовательно, стандарт это гарантирует (терминология [`sequence point`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Sequence-Points) в стандарте `C`, и `sequenced before`, `sequenced after` в `C++`). В вашем случае обязательно сначала установится флаг в 1, и только потом закроется дескриптор. Следует учитывать, выполнение двух этих операций вместе не является атомарным, между ними может выполнится код из другого потока, если необходимо предотвратить такое поведение, то нужен мьютекс или его аналог, что в любом случае требует создание новой переменной.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37102/discussion-on-answer-by-yuriy-orlov-atomic-----).

Answer (score 1):

@margosh, я все же написал тестик для проверки аналогичной (насколько я ее понял) ситуации.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <pthread.h>

volatile char end = 0;

void * 
f (void *a) 
{
  int fd = *(int *)a;

  for (;;) {  
    usleep(rand() % 1000);
    int i, l = read(fd, &i, sizeof(int));
    fprintf(stderr, "read %d (%d)\n", l, i);
    if (l == 0) {
      end = 1;
      close(fd);
      fputs("EOF\n", stderr);
      break;
    } 
    if (l < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "read %m\n");
      exit(3);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int i, pfd[2], fd;
  if (!pipe(pfd))
    fd = pfd[0];

  if (!fork()) {
    close(pfd[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (write(pfd[1], &i, sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int))
        fprintf(stderr, "child %d write %m\n", i);
      usleep(rand() % 1000);
    }
    close(pfd[1]);
    exit(0);
  }
  close(pfd[1]);

  pthread_t t;
  pthread_create(&t, 0, f, (void *)&fd);

  while (1) {
    struct timeval tm;
    tm.tv_sec = 2;
    tm.tv_usec = 0;
    fd_set rfd, efd;
    FD_ZERO(&rfd); FD_SET(fd, &rfd);
    FD_ZERO(&efd); FD_SET(fd, &efd);
    int n = select(fd + 1, &rfd, 0, &efd, &tm);
    fprintf(stderr, "select: %d\n", n);
    if (n < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "select (end = %d) %m\n", end);
      exit(2);
    } else if (n == 0)
      fprintf(stderr, "select timeout end = %d\n", end);
    else if (FD_ISSET(fd, &rfd)) 
      fputs("rfd\n", stderr);
    else if (FD_ISSET(fd, &efd)) {
      fputs("efd\n", stderr);
      exit(1);
    } else
      fputs("???\n", stderr);
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Оттранслировал с -О3 и вот таким образом

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ while true ; do ./a.out 2>&1 | grep '(end = ' ; done >/tmp/xres
```

запустил.

Сейчас уже

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ wc -l /tmp/xres 
5270 /tmp/xres
```

а промахов с volatile все нет.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ grep 0 /tmp/xres
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Перед вставкой случайных задержек я ее тоже гонял

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ wc -l /tmp/xres 
54619 /tmp/xres
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ grep 0 /tmp/xres
```

и тоже нолик не попадается.

Мне кажется, что ошибка все же в чем-то другом. Может какой-то не до конца оттестированный сигнал вмешался. SIGTERM, который при shutdown рассылается Вы как обрабатываете?

Comment: ситуация, которуя я Вам описала, - и есть обработка SIGTERM, только отложенная, в ней я как раз закрываю все дескрипторы.

Comment: @margosh, остается предположить, что этот дескриптор все же закрывается где-то в другом месте до описанного закрытия в первом потоке (или закрыт какой-то другой из передаваемых в select дескрипторов).